# Using Tim2 (84MHz) to blink Led for every 500ms - STM32F407VG

Tags: led, timer, stm32f4

I developped a code in ordrer to blink a Led every 500ms using the timer 2 with a frequency of 84Mhz.

I generate the file "system_stm32f4xx.c" to have a frequency of 84MHz for Tim2.

[image]

I modified the file "stm32f4xx.h" by adding the line

#define HSE_VALUE    ((uint32_t)8000000)

I modified the file "startup_stm32f4xx.c" by uncommenting the function SystemInit() and adding it before the main() in the function Default_Reset_Handler().

After that I created the project show below.

The problem is that I do not get the excepted result, The led blink every 100ms :

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_rcc.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_gpio.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_tim.h"

void InitializeLEDs()
{
RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);
GPIO_InitTypeDef gpioStructure;
gpioStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_12 ;
gpioStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
gpioStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
gpioStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
gpioStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &gpioStructure);
}

void InitializeTimer()
{
// Ftim2 = 84Mhz
TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef timerInitStructure;
RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM2, ENABLE);
timerInitStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 84000 - 1; // counter rate is 1ms
timerInitStructure.TIM_Period = 60000;
timerInitStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
timerInitStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = 0;
timerInitStructure.TIM_RepetitionCounter = 0;
TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM2, &timerInitStructure);
}

void delay_ms(uint16_t ms)
{
TIM_SetCounter(TIM2, 0);    // Make sure TIM2 Counter start from zero
TIM_Cmd(TIM2, ENABLE);              // Enalbe TIM2
while(TIM_GetCounter(TIM2) < ms);   // Wait ms Miliseconds
TIM_Cmd(TIM2, DISABLE);
}

int main(void)
{
InitializeLEDs();
InitializeTimer();
    while(1)
    {
        GPIO_SetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_12);
        delay_ms(500);
        GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_12);
        delay_ms(500);
    }
}
```

Here is the result :

[image]

Comment: "*The problem is that I do not get the excepted result.*" Well what result *do* you get. Put all the information **in your question** and then ask an actual question.

Comment: The result is showed on the last picture, the led is bliking just every 100ms

Comment: It's not a 100ms interval though, your picture shows it is about 109ms, and that's a clue to the specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to learn how to use those automatically generated code. Modifying them requires really good understanding of how it works.

As to your code, read the manual on how those functions work, in conjunction with the datasheet. Pay particular attention which variable is 16 bit or 32 bit so that your values given to those functions don't overflow.

Lastly write your code so that it does what you want to do. For example to produce a 0 5s delay on a 84mhz clock needs 42million cycles, to be broken down between the prescaler and the reload register. You can figure out what the right values should be.

It is sufficient to say that what you have aren't right.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I changed the values of Prescaler = 42000 - 1 and TIM_PERIOD = 1000 - 1 in order to get 42million cycles.

Answer (score 1):

The timer prescalar register is only 16 bits, so when you attempt to load the value of (84000-1) = 83999, the value you actually load is 83999-65536 = 18463.  Thus you divide the 84000 MHz clock by 18464 producing a 4.549 KHz count rather than a 1 KHz one.

This causes your attempted 500 milliseconds delay to be 4.549 times as fast as intended, resulting in an approximately 110 millisecond interval.

You may want to consider using the systick timer for timing instead, or calculating with a smaller hardware time interval (perhaps make it 5 KHz exactly), or perhaps even dividing the clock upstream of the timers if you only want to time slow events.

For that matter, you can run the PLL at a different multiplier to produce a slower system clock, if you have no need to do fast processing.  This will also save power.